# View table comment with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I view table comments in Oracle SQL Developer?

---

I added some comments:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE my_table_name IS 'Here are my table comments';
```

I know I can use some SQL query like `SELECT * FROM user_tab_comments;` to display the comments, but I am curious with it is possible to view them using  Oracle SQL Developer's GUI, as we can do for column comments by opening the "Columns" tab for a given table.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view the table comments by going to the "Details" tab and scrolling down:

[image]

Alternatively, you can right-click on the table, and select Table > Comment:

[image]

[image]

The second solution also allows you to edit the comment.